# Challenge with cleaning up JSON and export into JSONL

Tags: python, json

Breaking my brain on following challenge ..

Trying to clean up JSON sample data and trying to export it to a JSONL file.
Org JSON file:

```
{"data": {"allSites": {"activeSys": 123, "totalSys": 24718}},
 "sites": [{"accountId": "12345", "accountName": "system_a"},
           {"accountId": "67890","accountName": "system_b"}]}
```

Required JSONL data format:

```
{"accountId": "12345", "accounName": "system_a"}
{"accountId": "67890", "accounName": "system_b"}
```

Comment: parts that need to be removed : {"data": {"allSites": {"activeSys": 123, "totalSys": 24718},"sites": [ ]} .. .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` conversion as an
intermediate step in order to extract the desired part and then use `json.dumps` to convert to a pretty format for newly created json object such as

```
import json
import ast

Js= """{"data": {"allSites": {"activeSys": 123, "totalSys": 24718}},
        "sites": [{"accountId": "12345", "accountName": "system_a"},
                  {"accountId": "67890","accountName": "system_b"}]}"""

data = ast.literal_eval(Js)
newJs = data["sites"]

updatedJs = json.dumps(newJs, indent=4)
print(updatedJs)
```

if you want to read from a file(`json.file`) and write to another file(`data_new.json`), then use

```
import json
import ast

with open('data.json') as f, open('data_new.json', 'w') as f_out:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())    
    newJs = data["sites"]    
    f_out.write(format(newJs))
```